# Convert time from a 'series object of pandas.core.series module' into string in Python

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I need to get the value of the last cell of an Excel spreadsheet with Python using pandas.read_excel.
This cell contains a date that I need to assign to a variable in my Python script. The format is 2018-10-15 21:20:00.

I need to convert this date into string without the time part, so in this example I just need 2018-10-15.

I've tried:

```
pd.read_excel('spreadsheet.xlsx')['column1'][-1:].astype('datetime64[D]')
```

but when I use .values() to extract the value of it I get 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

I've also tried:

```
pd.read_excel('spreadsheet.xlsx')['column1'][-1:].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I get 'Series object has no attribute strftime'.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First `pd.DataFrame.values` is an attribute not a method, so it's not callable,
Then, the easiest way to convert string to time series is to use pd.to_datetime function why allow you to add a format argument, in your case

```
series= pd.read_excel('spreadsheet.xlsx')['column1'][-1:]
series= pd.to_datetime(series.apply(lamba x: x[:10]), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note that the lambda function allow you to keep only the first 10 letters of the string content,
Here is a very good doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the date from the timestamp as in the values of `b` below, first make sure the dtype for the series is a datetime object and then use `dt.date` to extract just the date:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['2018-10-16 22:20:00', '2018-10-15 18:20:00','2018-10-18 21:20:00']})

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   a                    b
0  1  2018-10-16 22:20:00
1  2  2018-10-15 18:20:00
2  3  2018-10-18 21:20:00

In [26]: df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b'])

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   a                   b
0  1 2018-10-16 22:20:00
1  2 2018-10-15 18:20:00
2  3 2018-10-18 21:20:00

In [28]: df['b'].dtype
Out[28]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [33]: df['date'] = df['b'].dt.date

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   a                   b        date
0  1 2018-10-16 22:20:00  2018-10-16
1  2 2018-10-15 18:20:00  2018-10-15
2  3 2018-10-18 21:20:00  2018-10-18
```

Comment: It works thanks but I still struggle to extract the date only.
It returns:
"205673   2019-04-29
Name: column1, dtype: object"

205673 being the row of the cell in Excel.

I just need '2019-04-29'.

Comment: In my example, the `b` column had perfect datetime strings, maybe your column has random text and datetime values. Can you show a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: My dataframe has datetime values of form : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.
It's not string.